# Private Message Bot Discord

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js, private-messaging

I want to add a feature to the bot, to contact a user in private with his id in parameter.

I already tried this:

```
sendMessage(idUser, "mesage")
```

but it doesn't work.

I have this error:

> "sendMessage is not defined"

Comment: you need to give more details what you have tried so far

Comment: i have tried this : 

bot.sendMessage(user, "my message");
bot.message(user, "my message");

I want to know if it's possible to contact a user in private message with this id, cause i don't find anything about private message by userId

Comment: u need to add some more code how u are doing this so that we can understand what is problem

Comment: const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()

bot.on('message' function(message)){
        sendMessage( auserid , "HELLO WORLD")
}

You don't need the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try `message.author.send("Your message here");`
This takes the author of the sent message and sends a message to them.

Please note for the future, however, that sendMessage is depreciated in discord.js. Instead, just use send.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah `message.author.send("MESSAGE")` should work

Also a little handy tip `\n` makes a new line if your making lines of text :D